# Should I use my residual's data to model if it has a lower p-value?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

I ran the Dickey-Fuller Test on my original dataset and on my residual values.

and got these results.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the p-value for both tests allowed me to reject my null hypothesis, which passed the stationarity test. But the p-value for the residuals is considerably lower than the original.

Should I consider modeling using the residuals instead of my original data values?